# How to prevent clutter and save api calls in a different file? (python)

Tags: python, api

For a webapp project I'm making multiple api calls. Each is a long link so my file is looking pretty cluttered.
I tried making a seperate file in which I can store my api calls, but the problem I then encountered was that the api calls get made when the file is loaded. This is obviously something I don't want.

What I think will work is making a function for each api call and store these functions in the other file, but to me this seems a bit overkill and not very beautiful.

Is there some better way I don't know about?

Edit: I can't just save the string, because the api is id dependent.

sample api call:

```
video = requests.get(f'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{id}/videos?api_key=e7319c984bf89b3efa98e5a0106691b7&language=en-US')
```

Comment: pls give samples of your api call

Comment: @AajKaal I added a sample